# how can I query the integers between two values by creating a list of those integers in Prolog.?

Tags: prolog

For example, If I make a query like `between(A,4,7)`, I would expect something like `A = [4,5,6]`. Is this possible?

Comment: "Is this possible?" impossible is nothing. Now do some reading and writing instead of hoping someone on the internets does your work for you. You won't get it even if the right answer smacks you in the face. PS: look [here](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#numlist/3) for an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
?- bagof(A, between(4,7,A), All).
All = [4, 5, 6, 7].
```

This uses SWI-Prolog's builtin [between/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3), which seems to have a slightly different definition from yours.

You can also use setof/3, to ensure that the results are ordered -- `bagof/3` will deliver the results according to the backtracking of `betweeen/3`.

Comment: It is likely that the _expected solution_ is something along the lines of [numlist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#numlist/3)